# WorkSite SDK - Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: vb.net, com, sdk, autonomy

I am attempting to learn how to develop applications to interact with the Autonomy WorkSite 8.5 server and have found the WorkSite DB Administrators COM Developers Reference Guide, it has helped me somewhat and I can now see the types of objects that I can interface with however, I am stumbling on showing the members of a group.

My code is as follows. This is for a VB.NET Windows Forms application.

```
Dim ObjNRDMS As IMANADMIN.NRTDMS
Dim ObjSessions As IMANADMIN.NRTSessions
Dim ObjSession As IMANADMIN.NRTSession
Dim ServerName As String
ServerName = "SERVERNAME"
' Create the NRTDMS object
ObjNRDMS = GetObject("IMANADMIN.NRTDMS")
' Add the Server to the NRTSessions object and
' get a NRTSession object for the server
ObjSessions = ObjNRDMS.Sessions
ObjSessions.Add(ServerName)
ObjSession = ObjSessions.Item(1)
' Login to the Server
ObjSession.TrustedLogin()

Dim ObjDBs As IMANADMIN.NRTDatabases
Dim ObjDB As IMANADMIN.NRTDatabase
Dim ObjGroup As IMANADMIN.NRTGroup
' ObjSession is a previously defined NRTSession object
' Get the first database defined for ObjSession object
ObjDBs = ObjSession.Databases
ObjDB = ObjDBs.Item(1)
ObjGroup = ObjDB.GetGroup("TEST")
txtOutput.AppendText(ObjGroup.Users.ToString)
```

However, when I debug this code in Visual Studio (2008), I get the error:

> Cannot create ActiveX component at the line `ObjNRDMS =
>   GetObject("IMANADMIN.NRTDMS")

I have run regsvr32 iManAdmin.dll.

Can anyone offer any assistance on this problem?

I've read on page 21 of the DB Admin COM guide that it mentions to execute iManAdmin - REGSERVER from the command prompt, however this will not work for me with Windows reporting that the file does not have a open with program set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by using the iManage worksite `Interop.iManAdmin.dll`

Comment: can you expand on your solution? i am getting the same error but i don't understand how to use Interop.iManAdmin.dll